# My network adapter "D-Link DWA-547" is causing windows 7 to freeze

Tags: windows-7, networking

Any audio playing, and sometimes the program i am using is constantly stuttering and freezing up. I have narrowed the offending hardware down to my:D-Link DWA-547 RangeBooster N650 Desktop Adapter

If I disable it in the device manager everything runs fine and smooth.

The card works, and gives me super fast internet. But the rest of the system hangs.

I have tried installing the card with the drivers from the cd that came with it, i also tried the lates beta drivers from the d-link webpage, but the problem persists.
What do i do?

Comment: There are no consumer motherboards that accept two processors. There are, however, many motherboards that will accept dual-core chips, which is NOT THE SAME as two physical processors, with two separate heatsinks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so i solved the problem i installed an older vista atheros driver since d-link uses this chipset.
More specifically the v7.7.0.396

http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/14833-latest-atheros-wlan-drivers-for-windows-7-and-vista-x86-x64/

Answer (score 1):

Install the corresponding Windows XP driver manually. This solved the problem for me.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drivers that came with the card were likely not tested with the released version of Windows 7.  They were likely written for an earlier version of Windows and may not work as expected with Windows 7.

The beta drivers that you downloaded are just that, a beta.  They are supposed to be tested for problems, and then the problems reported back to the developers.  Perhaps you should close the loop and report the problem to the developers of the beta drivers.

Until you can get some known-working drivers for Windows 7, please consider purchasing a [network card that is known to work correctly with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?type=Hardware&s=Wireless%20N%20Adapter).

Comment: Well as much as i would love a card that is compatible with windows 7 it's not really an option to just buy another. If you have any suggestions on how i could solve the problem with the hardware at hand i would apreciate it.

Comment: A compatible card... like perhaps the D-Link DWA-547? http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=D-Link%20RangeBooster%20N%20650%20Desktop%20Cardbus%20Wireless%20Network%20Adapter&v=D-Link&uid=DWA-547&l=en-US&pf=4&pi=0&s=Wireless%20N%20Adapter&os=64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with 2 different and comlete new adapters on 3 different computers with XP Pro, and Win 7 Ultimate. No driver seems to solve the freezing problem nor the unstability of the computers. It all boils down to the DWA 547 adapters, that must be a very bad product. It is funny though, because I have 2 other DWA 547 adapters running in 2 different computers, and there are absolutely no problems with them. The adapters are a bit older and have a different size than the newest, but are still called DWA 547. They are running win 7 Ultimate without any problems. Strange.....

Anyway, I will return the non working card and puchase a new one,but NOT D-Link!